# Locate index where string1 contains string 2?

Tags: java, string

I have two strings: stringOne and stringTwo.

```
String stringOne = "JAVA";
String stringTwo = "DJDFKWAUERHFGJAVAORKFLASOWE";
```

I can easily locate if Java is in the second string (it is), where how would I index where it begins and ends? I want to initialize the beginning and end positions in integer variables: `begPos = 14` and `endPos = 18`. What method would I use to do this?

Somewhat the reverse of this, but I also have a third string:

```
String stringThree = "                          ";
```

It's a bunch of whitespace. I want to put "JAVA" in there according to the positions gained before. I can replace parts of a string with other parts of a string, but again I'm not sure how to replace a specific position. The end result should be:

```
String stringThree = "              JAVA      ";
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Using String method 'int indexOf(String)'.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html - know where to look (the API)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `str.indexOf(substr)` which returns the index of a substring into `str`, and the `str.substring(start, end)` methods:

> **public String substring(int beginIndex,
>                  int endIndex)**
>   Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at index endIndex - 1. Thus the length of the substring is endIndex-beginIndex.

**Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String stringOne = "JAVA";
    String stringTwo = "DJDFKWAUERHFGJAVAORKFLASOWE";

    int begPos = stringTwo.indexOf(stringOne);
    int endPos = begPos + stringOne.length();

    System.out.println(begPos + " " + endPos);

    String stringThree = "......................";
    stringThree = stringThree.substring(0, begPos) + stringOne + stringThree.substring(endPos);

    System.out.println(stringThree);
}
```

You would like to manipulate the `start` and `end` arguments passed to `substring(start, end)` in order to get the expected output.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the `indexOf()` method.

Answer (score 3):

```
String stringOne = "JAVA";
String stringTwo = "DJDFKWAUERHFGJAVAORKFLASOWE";
int begin=stringTwo.indexOf(stringOne);
int end=begin+stringOne.length();
if(begin==-1){
    //not found
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify the string, use StringBuilder.

```
String str = "                            ";
String ins = "JAVA";
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(str);
String result = builder.replace(14, 18, ins).toString();
```